# Selecionar itens do banco de dados que contenham algo similar ao conteúdo de uma array

Tags: php, mysql

Supondo que eu tenha a seguinte array `array("valor1", "valor2", "valor3", "valor4", "valor5")` e preciso pegar **todos** os itens de uma tabela do MySQL cuja coluna **X** tenha valor igual a um destes itens, como proceder?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode montar sua query de duas formas.

**Primeira Forma**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN (";

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    $query .= "'" . $value . "', ";

$query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-2) . ")";
```

**Segunda Forma**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE";

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    $query .= " col = '" . $value . "' OR";

$query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-3) . ")";
```

A diferença entre as duas formas fica na forma em que a condição é escrita. *Considero a primeira forma como melhor, por deixar o tamanho da condição menor, mais organizado e mais legível*.

**Primeira Forma:**  `... WHERE col IN ('valor 1', 'valor2', 'valor3')`

**Segunda Forma:**  `... WHERE col = 'valor 1' OR col = 'valor2' OR col = 'valor3'`

Answer (score 0):

Monte sua query assim:

```
$array =  array(0 => "valor1", 
                        1 => "valor2",
                        2 => "valor3",
                        3 => "valor4");

$query = "SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE";

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $query .= " `campo_x` = '" . $v . "' OR";

}

//Retiro o último OR
$query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-2);

//O resultado deve ser:
//SELECT * FROM sua_tabela WHERE `campo_x` = 'valor1' OR `campo_x` = 'valor2'...
```

Agora é só fazer sua query:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "senha", "db");

$mysqli->query($query);
```